# Firebase otp recaptcha error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am using firebase to generate otp and i am getting an error about appVerificationDisabledForTesting being undefined.

```
recaptcha_verifier.ts:114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')
    at new RecaptchaVerifier (recaptcha_verifier.ts:114:1)
    at generateRecaptcha (Home.js:123:1)
    at handleSend (Home.js:139:1)
```

here is the code i am using

```
const handleSend = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    generateRecaptcha();
    let appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
        // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Error; SMS not sent
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

the error is coming from  generateRecaptcha();

```
const generateRecaptcha = () => {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      "recaptcha",
      {
        size: "invisible",
        callback: (response) => {
          // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
          // ...
        },
      },
      auth
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change the arrangement on initiating `RecaptchaVerifier`, like this:

Firebase < 9:
`new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {}, auth);`

Firebase > 10:
`new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'recaptcha-container', {});`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"firebase": "^9.4.1"

change the firebase version to 9.4.1 and it will work i too got stuck with this error and have been searching for the solution this is the only solution i got for now

Answer (score -1):

IT WORKED      ******

before :
function setUpRecaptha(number) {
const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
"recaptcha-container",
{},
auth
);
recaptchaVerifier.render();
return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, recaptchaVerifier);
}

after :    function setUpRecaptha(number) {
const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth,
"recaptcha-container",
{}
);
recaptchaVerifier.render();
return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, recaptchaVerifier);
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).